# Error while reading csv file (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode, syntax-error

I am trying to read a csv file in python(jupyter notebook) but getting an error. Below is the code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import sklearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pwd
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\creditcard.csv")
```

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6kl7.png

Edit: I've tried all of the following and still getting the same error.

```
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\creditcard.csv")
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\creditcard.csv")
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\creditcard.csv")
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\creditcard.csv")

data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/creditcard.csv")
data = pd.read_csv("C://Users//DELL//Desktop//creditcard.csv")
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/creditcard.csv")
data = pd.read_csv(r"C://Users//DELL//Desktop//creditcard.csv")
```

Also, I've tried all of them with a single quote (') but its no use. Here's a picture of the file details:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmeoB.png

Comment: @MayankPorwal I've tried this but still getting the same error.

Comment: The duplicate question does address and fix the problem *that you described*. If it still doesn't work, then either something went wrong in running the new code (e.g. make sure you saved the .py file before trying again) or there is a *new* problem that demands a new question and a *complete* stack trace specific to the new problem. You might *think* you get "the same error", but it could easily have changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try any of the following solutions:-

```
1: By putting r converts normal string to raw string:
    pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\creditcard.csv")

2: Replacing with double backward-slash:
    pandas.read_csv("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\creditcard.csv")

3: Replacing with forward-slash:    
    pandas.read_csv("C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/creditcard.csv")
```

Comment: Instead of putting the same answer again, please point to the existing answer. That will keep SO clean.

Comment: I think it's alright like this. It's clearly more informative than the first answer. One could mention that parts of it were said before, but omitting Option 1 just because somebody else brought it up before would be less of a good answer.

Comment: @Shreyansh Jain did you try the above solution

Comment: @LovleenKaur yes I did but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

try this. will fix the issue.

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\creditcard.csv.csv")
```

Comment: Can you include an explanation of why and how this solves it, and why this is a better answer than the existing answers?

Comment: why the .csv.csv?

Comment: well i was trapped in the same scenerio as the above user. even tried all of them "/" "//" etc all of em as  mentioned above. well in my case the problem i had was ,the name of the  dataset itself was "creditcard.csv"  so i did give it  a try "/creditcard.csv.csv"   it worked. well i know its not too technical but i just shared my solution.hope it worked.